# Functional programming syntax in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, runnable

I was reading about **Functional Programming** and its implementation in Java. I came across this example which has some different syntax than **Object Oriented Programming in Java.** Is it that functional programming has some different syntax?

```
public class Hello {
    Runnable r1 = ()->(System.out.println(this);};
    Runnable r2 = ()->(System.out.println(toString());};
    public String toString(){ return “Howdy!”;}
    public static void main(String args) {
        new Hello().r1.run();
        new Hello().r2.run();
    }
```

After going through the code, I could understand that parenthesis is not matched properly, the syntax is not similar to Java syntax for OOP.

This code doesn't compile and gives following error on all the lines:

```
Hello.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Runnable r2 = ()->(System.out.println(toString());};
```

What is it that I am missing? If this program is correct, what shall it print?
I am using **javac 1.8.0_66** on **Ubuntu 14.04.3**

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors. It should be :

```
Runnable r1 = ()->{System.out.println(this);};
Runnable r2 = ()->{System.out.println(toString());};
```

Those are lambda expressions. This will also work :

```
Runnable r1 = ()->System.out.println(this);
Runnable r2 = ()->System.out.println(toString());
```

This program will print `Howdy` twice, since that's what the `toString` method of your `Hello` class returns, and `this` inside a lambda expression refers to the instance in which the lambda expression is declared.

Comment: Thank you, Eran for the response. This was very helpful.